# What is the sum of maxterms \$M4+M7\$?

Tags: karnaugh-map

I dont really get min/max terms. I think for filling into K-Maps, m1 (minterm 1), I will put 1 into the box for 1. For maxterm M1, I will fill 0 into box for 1? But if the question is "What is the sum of maxterms \$M4+M7\$?". What do I do?

Comment: Please don't use the `homework` tag in the future, it's deprecated (I'm trying to get it blacklisted).

Comment: @stevenvh, I understand that. Thats why I had the footnote saying I am not sure what tag to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Boolean function of four variables, the maxterm M4 equals 0100 which represents `a + b' + c + d`. Convention says to use 1 for complemented variables. The 0100 in binary notation equals 4 in decimal.

Similarly, the minterm m4 equals 0100, and convention says it represents `a' b c' d'`.

To compute `M4 + M7`, consider expanding the maxterms to their Boolean equivalents and performing the summation.

See also:

- [Karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) (Wikipedia)
- [Canonical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form_%28Boolean_algebra%29#Minterms) (Wikipedia)